# Particle system within a drawing in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I'm trying to create a particle system within a basic-shape drawing. The particles should emit from the top of the leftmost structure (commented "Heading") and flow downwards, similar to a fountain. I have a majority of the Particle class figured out, but error messages related to the variables arise when I run the sketch.

Applied some edits based on answers, but cannot get the particle system to display. Amended code listed below.

```
var particles = [ ];

function Particle() {
  initialization() 
    this.x = 135;
    this.y = 75;
    this.vx = random(-1, 1);
    this.vx = random(-5, -1);
    this.alpha = 255;
  
  update() 
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;
    this.alpha -= 5;
  
  show() 
    noStroke();
    fill ('#1E740C');
    ellipse (this.x, this.y, 8, 8);
}

function setup() {  
  createCanvas(600, 400);
  
  //Particle Array
  for(var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
  particles[i] = new Particle();
  }
}

function draw() {  
  background('#87D9E8'); 
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(1);
  
    //Loop array and alter each element
  for(var i=0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    particles[i].show();
    particles[i].update();
  }
  
//SLIME GEYSER
  
///Center Pipe
  fill ('#1FA600');
  rect(340, 75, 20, 290);
  rect(340, 75, 130, 20);
  
////Body
  fill ('#1FA600');
  ellipse (305, 495, 450, 400);
  
///Heading (Spout)
 //rect(100, 140, 80, 140, 15); //Top segment
 //triangle (100, 150, 180, 150, 140, 100); //"Neck" segment
 // rect(120, 75, 40, 40); //SPOUT TIP
 // ellipse(140, 115, 100, 45); //Spout "bulb"  
  rect(120, 350, 40, 30); //Bottom pipe
  rect(100, 290, 80, 60, 20); //Bottom segment
  rect(100, 277, 80, 15); //Midway segment
  
//////Pressure Condenser Unit Grille
  fill('#989E9B');
  rect(390, 135, 140, 130);
  line (410, 305, 410, 100);
  line (430, 305, 430, 100);
  line (450, 305, 450, 100);
  line (470, 305, 470, 100);
  line (490, 305, 490, 100);
  line (510, 305, 510, 100);
  
////Pressure Condenser Unit
  fill ('#1FA600');
  arc(460, 265, 140, 140, 0, HALF_PI+HALF_PI);
  arc(460, 135, 140, 140, PI, 0);
  
////Tube
  noFill();
  stroke('#1FA250');
  strokeWeight(10);
  beginShape();
  vertex(110, 270);
  quadraticVertex(10, 200, 110, 150);
  endShape();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't have to declare a global Particle variable, the class would do it.

You aren't calling the show function on the particles array so it won't display the particles.

Instead you can do something like this,

```
function Particle() {
                                
                this.x = 120; 
                this.y = 200; 
                this.vx = random(-1,1); 
                this.vy = random(-5,1); 
                
                this.alpha = 255; 
            
                this.show = function() { 
                                noStroke(); 
                                fill("#1E740C"); 
                                
                                ellipse(this.x, this.y, 8, 8);
                                
                }
                
                this.update = function() {
                                this.x += this.vx;
                                this.y += this.vy;
                                //console.log("run")
                }
}

var p = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(345,400);
                
                for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                                p[i] = new Particle();
                }
}

function draw() {
                
                background(0);
                
                for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                                
                                p[i].show();
                                p[i].update()
                }
}
```

That's probably the easiest way to create the particles system. If this answer wasn't helpful then checkout these links:
CodingTrain: https://thecodingtrain.com/CodingChallenges/078-simple-particle-system.html

Or check out p5's own example:
https://p5js.org/examples/simulate-multiple-particle-systems.html

Comment: Where would I put these in relation to the drawing?  I'm pretty much asking if I should declare the particle system's stuff (the array in setup-function and the loop in draw-function) before or after the shapes in the code.

Comment: Are you going to keep the shapes outside the draw? Add the particle stuff before the shapes. I hope, it shouldn't be a problem. Try it, if it doesn't work we will figure it out.

Comment: I added everything and got two error messages: **"Particle has already been declared"** (in reference to the 'var particles = [ ]' array) and **"Cannot access Particle before Initialization"**.  I'll put this in my original question.

Comment: Replace ```i <= particles.length``` with ```i < particles.length``` first. Now move the Particle class to the top of the file. I ran your code, everything is working fine on my machine.

Comment: Of course, the particle class would go underneath the global variable ``var particles = [ ]``, correct?

Comment: Add the class before declaring it. Doesn't matter if it's before or after the particles array.

Comment: I am still receiving two error messages pertaining to the class: ***"Particle has already been declared"*** and ***"Cannot read property 'show' of undefined."***  Everything else appears to be in order, just the class seems to be the issue.  Edited my original code in the main question.

Comment: For the <b>cannot read property error</b>, replace `i <= particles.length` with `i < particles.length`in the draw. And also try this for the class ```function Particle() { //var initialization (use this.x, this.y etc)this.show = function() { //show code }  this.update = function() { //update code}  }```

Comment: I think I got it to work by making "Particle" a function. That cleared the error messages, but now the particles aren't displaying.  Should I have kept it a class while keeping the same constructor values?  I assume those would go under the 'initialization' command.

Comment: You don't have to declare `initialization()`. Just declare the variables. Comment out `particles[i].update()`. When I called update it also didn't display anything for me. I moved `update()` after the `show()`. It seems to be working. Also you have two `this.vx`. So change one to `this.vy`.

Comment: https://thecodingtrain.com/CodingChallenges/078-simple-particle-system.html is dead